# How to use standalone TypeScript library in Vue.js project?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, webpack

I have developed a standalone TypeScript library for rendering purposes, and I have installed it in the Vue.js project.
But whenever I try to build the Vue.js project after importing and using a class from this library I get the build error saying:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/standalone-library/dist/bundle.es.min.js 66:144935
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (66:144935)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

I don't know how to solve this particular issue.

Comment: It sounds like the rest of your project doesn't use typescript? Or the standalone library is not compiled down to javascript?

Comment: It's unknown how the project is configured and how the lib is compiled. bundle.es.min.js should preferably be built to es6 or es5 with es modules. It's unknown what "Unexpected token (66:144935)" refers to.

Comment: @Kokodoko, yes the project in which I am using this TS library is vue.js project and currently it is using JavaScript.

Comment: @EstusFlask bundle.es.min.js is built for es5 modules.

Comment: Then the problem is in your setup and how you use the lib. You can start with checking what's wrong with the line the error refers. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , it's necessary for code-related problems.